# Windows App: Render directx only in a part of the App

Tags: c++, directx

I'm writing an application which should use DirectX2D, but only in a part of the window. The window should have buttons and input areas to control the DirectX-Area ...

I'm using Visual C++ with Visual Studio 2015.

Can anyone help me? Or are there some sample codes for that?

Thanks for your help! <3

Answer (score 0):

You can create child window without borders and position it inside your app window. And create Direct2D context for that child window. You can also use DC render target (`ID2D1Factory::CreateDCRenderTarget`) and bind it to any window DC and specific region.
I use the latter approach for my 2D graphics library.